# Web access using preshared token?

Tags: authentication, web

A few years back I read an article about a method of providing users of a web site with a preshared token or code that authorized them to access the web site.  Without the token/code already installed, you were prevented from accessing the site.  I can't find references to that method nor can I find anything in my notes about what it was called.  Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I found my notes containing the answer.  For those interested, it is called "https ssl client authentication"